# Invalid argument for "-t --tag" flag: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, docker-build

I'm trying to build the docker image using this script:

release.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

export ENV="prod"
export REGISTRY_HOST="registry.seesunit.kr"
export IMAGE_PREFIX="$ENV-scim"
export IMAGE_TARGET="web"
export IMAGE_NAME="$REGISTRY_HOST/$IMAGE_PREFIX-$IMAGE_TARGET"
export DOCKER_ROOT="/home/dev-admin/docker"
export DOCKER_PATH="$DOCKER_ROOT/$IMAGE_PREFIX/$ENV-$IMAGE_TARGET"

#echo "CONTAINER > "
#docker container ls | grep $IMAGE_NAME #| grep -Eo "^[^ ]+"
echo "IMAGES > "
docker images | grep $IMAGE_NAME #| grep -Eo "^[^ ]+"

echo "Input IMAGE_TAG :"
read IMAGE_TAG

echo "TAG=$IMAGE_TAG" > $DOCKER_PATH/.env
echo "IMAGE_NAME=$IMAGE_NAME" >> $DOCKER_PATH/.env
echo "TAG=$IMAGE_TAG" > .env
echo "IMAGE_NAME=$IMAGE_NAME" >> .env

docker-compose -f $DOCKER_PATH/docker-compose.yml down

#echo "Q4. DOCKER_ID_USER?"
#read DOCKER_ID_USER
docker rmi -f $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG

docker build -f ./tools/$ENV.Dockerfile -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .

#docker tag $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $DOCKER_ID_USER/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
#docker push $DOCKER_ID_USER/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG

#docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG

docker-compose -f $DOCKER_PATH/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

**Current containers**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                     NAMES
dad647696802   registry.seesunit.kr/prod-scim-web:v_db   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 weeks ago   Up 2 weeks   0.0.0.0:30080->80/tcp, :::30080->80/tcp   prod-web_prod-web_1
```

When I tried to run `docker build` from the command line:

```
docker build -f ./tools/$ENV.Dockerfile -t prod-web_prod-web_1:registry.seesunit.kr/prod-scim-web:v_db .
```

I got an error like this:

```
invalid argument "prod-web_prod-web_1:registry.seesunit.kr/prod-scim-web:v_db" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
```

I'm running on Windows.

Comment: From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/,  I'm guessing you have the Image_tag and Image_name the wrong way around?  (Just a guess... I could be wrong)

Comment: you have 2 `:`s, but expected is only 1.

Comment: @LeiYang you means one in this `registry.seesunit.kr/prod-scim-web:v_db`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it says, your image name/tag is invalid.

Image names are slash-separated. You can prefix with a registry address including optional port number.

your `prod-web_prod-web_1:registry.seesunit.kr/prod-scim-web:v_db` has too many colons. My guess is that the first bit is there by error and what you want is
`registry.seesunit.kr/prod-scim-web:v_db`, i.e. your build command should be

```
docker build -f ./tools/$ENV.Dockerfile -t registry.seesunit.kr/prod-scim-web:v_db .
```

Answer (score 10):

```
-t prod-web_prod-web_1:registry.seesunit.kr/prod-scim-web:v_db
                      ^                                  ^
                      |                                  |
```

You have two colons (`:`) in your `name:tag` argument.

Docker thinks your image tag is `registry.seesunit.kr/prod-scim-web:v_db` which contains a colon, and from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/:

> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.